# jar dependencies in android- no class definition found exception

Tags: java, android, jar

I resolved this issue myself.  It turns out that the activation framework requires some libraries that aren't native to android, myjava.awt.datatransfer, org.apache.harmony.awt.*, and org.apache.harmony.misc.  Once i added those libraries everything worked fine.

> I'm trying to use the gdata java
>   client library on android and have
>   managed a decent hack to get it
>   working.  However because the jar for
>   gdata had some package discrepancies
>   with android I had to import the
>   source into my project.  This source
>   is dependent on the JavaMail API and
>   the JavaBeans Activation Framework as
>   specified [here](http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/articles/java_client_lib.html#mac).
>
> My issue is that the JavaMail jar
>   throws a class definition not found
>   when seeking a class which is in the
>   Activation Framework jar.  A stack
>   trace is listed below.  I am working
>   in Eclipse and have both jars in a lib
>   folder and added to my build path. 
>   I'm not very experienced dealing with
>   jars in a  situation like this so any
>   help or insight would be appreciated.

```
03-29 09:55:26.204: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(331): Uncaught handler: thread AsyncTask #3 exiting due to uncaught exception
03-29 09:55:26.215: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(331): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
03-29 09:55:26.215: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(331):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
03-29 09:55:26.215: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(331):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
03-29 09:55:26.215: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(331):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
03-29 09:55:26.215: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(331):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
03-29 09:55:26.215: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(331):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
03-29 09:55:26.215: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(331):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
03-29 09:55:26.215: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(331):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
03-29 09:55:26.215: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(331):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
03-29 09:55:26.215: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(331): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.activation.DataHandler
03-29 09:55:26.215: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(331):     at javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.setContent(MimeBodyPart.java:684)
03-29 09:55:26.215: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(331):     at com.google.gdata.data.media.MediaBodyPart.<init>(MediaBodyPart.java:95)
03-29 09:55:26.215: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(331):     at com.google.gdata.data.media.MediaMultipart.<init>(MediaMultipart.java:126)
03-29 09:55:26.215: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(331):     at com.google.gdata.client.media.MediaService.insert(MediaService.java:382)
03-29 09:55:26.215: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(331):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
03-29 09:55:26.215: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(331):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue myself. It turns out that the activation framework requires some libraries that aren't native to android, myjava.awt.datatransfer, org.apache.harmony.awt.*, and org.apache.harmony.misc. Once i added those libraries everything worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it doesn't support android.  Maybe in a future SDK.  [Link](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-java-client/issues/detail?id=221)
Since it runs with the Davlik Runtime and not the standard JRE there are
probably missing classes that aren't in the Davlik JRE.

Comment: that bug linked is actually one I've already dealt with this one is specific to the activation and mail jars.  I'm beginning to think i'll simply have to include the source for those jars as well.